# SELECT DISTINCT rows FROM one table HAVING MIN(value) FROM another table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have one table (**table1**) with columns:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |

and another table (**table2**) with columns:

| ID | table1.ID | DATE | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 21-JUL-2020 | INACTIVE |
| 2 | 1 | 22-JUL-2022 | ACTIVE |
| 3 | 1 | 23-JUL-2022 | ACTIVE |
| 4 | 2 | 21-JAN-2022 | ACTIVE |
| 5 | 2 | 22-JAN-2022 | INACTIVE |
| 6 | 2 | 23-JAN-2022 | ACTIVE |
| 7 | 3 | 20-JAN-2022 | INACTIVE |
| 8 | 3 | 20-JAN-2022 | INACTIVE |

I am trying to write a query that will return distinct rows from **table1** where status from **table2** is `ACTIVE` and results should be ordered by min DATE from **table2**.
Desired result:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | B |
| 1 | A |

I tried with the following:

```
select t1, min(t2.date) 
from table1 t1 join t1.t2List t2  -- table1 Entity has OneToMany t2List defined
where t2.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by t1.id
order by t2.date desc;
```

Problem here is that I can't use my Entity class **table1** and I would like to avoid creating a new class that will hold this additional aggregated result (min date).

Also tried using HAVING clause but could not get it working.

```
select t1 from table1 t1
where t1.id in (
select table1.id from table2 t2 where t2.status = 'ACTIVE'
group by t1.id, t2.date
having t2.date = min(t2.date));
```

Appriciete any help here!

Comment: For `table1.ID = 1`, the record with minimum date in that group is inactive, not active.  Please explain your sample data.

Comment: *and results should be ordered by min DATE from table2* Even when this minimal date have another status?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Desired result data is from table1. There is ACTIVE record for table1.ID = 1 with date=22-JUL-2022 and ID=2.

Comment: @Akina No. Note that there is not result in desired result table with ID=3 since there is no ACTIVE record for table1.ID=3

Comment: You don't understand me. Imagine: ID=11, 10-JUL-2020 INACTIVE, 13-JUL-2020 ACTIVE; ID=22, 11-JUL-2020 INACTIVE, 12-JUL-2020 ACTIVE. Which must be first? What date must be used - the oldest at all or the oldest with ACTIVE status?

Comment: @Akina the oldest with ACTIVE status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join `table1` to a query that aggregates in `table2` and returns all `table1_id`s with an `ACTIVE` row:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT table1_id, MIN(date) date
  FROM table2
  WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
  GROUP BY table1_id
) t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
ORDER BY t2.date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c817c9d239a5eb8b101ef77c7b92c91).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of solving this problem, as @forpas has already answered
using a subquery in the JOIN clause.

The same results can be achieved using this query

```
SELECT table1.ID , table1.name
FROM table1  
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.table1_ID = table1.ID
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY table1.ID , table1.name
ORDER BY MIN(table2.statusDate)
```